# Map icon doesn't return to normal size when a new one is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

My click function isn't returning map icons to their original size when a new marker is clicked and I can't seem to figure out why. Here's the code I'm using:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    disableAutoPan: true,
    isHidden:false,
    closeBoxURL: "",
    pane: "mapPane",
    enableEventPropagation: true
});
var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng( locations[i][1], locations[i][2] ),
        map: map,
        id: (locations[i][3]),
        icon: (locations[i][4]),
        optimize: false,
        title: (locations[i][0]),
        description: (locations[i][6])
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
        return function () {
            infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0], locations[i][6]);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
            map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
            sidebar.open('destination' + [i]);
            marker.setIcon(locations[i][5]);
        };
    })(marker, i));
    
    markers.push(marker);
}
```

When clicked, the icon enlarges like I want it to and the info window appears. When I click on another icon the info window closes on the previous marker and moves to the new marker, but the previous marker is still large.

The map has multiple marker images for different categories so I can't just assign a single icon and change the size. In the database I have 2 image sizes for each marker, the smaller is called as "(locations[i][4])" and the larger one as "(locations[i][5])".

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

What you could try doing would be to set further custom properties for each marker as you construct them which would become available in the `click` handler as properties of that marker. To some extent you have started that process by including custom properties such as `optimize` - taking it a step further though like this perhaps ( wholly untested ) approach:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    disableAutoPan: true,
    isHidden:false,
    closeBoxURL: '',
    pane: 'mapPane',
    enableEventPropagation: true
});

var clickhandler=function(e){
    /* set properties of the InfoWindow */
    infowindow.setContent( this.content );
    infowindow.open( map, this );
    map.setCenter( this.getPosition() );
    
    /* Custom tasks */
    sidebar.open('destination' + this.index );
    
    /* inspect the marker `images` property to get new image - large */
    this.setIcon( this.images.large );
};

var toggleimages=function(){
    markers.forEach( mkr=>{
        mkr.setIcon( mkr.images.small )
    })
};

var marker,properties;


for ( var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++ ) {
    /* 
        Create the standard markr properties with a few "custom" properties
        added to aid the icon swapping.
        
        New properties:
            images
            content
            index
        
        Moved outwith the new Marker constructor for easier reading only 
    */
    properties={
        index:i,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng( locations[i][1], locations[i][2] ),
        map: map,
        id:locations[i][3],
        icon:locations[i][4],
        optimize:false,
        title:locations[i][0],
        description:locations[i][6],
        
        images:{
            large:locations[i][5],
            small:locations[i][4]
        },
        content:[ locations[i][0], locations[i][6] ].join(', ')
    };
    
    
    
    /* create the marker */
    marker = new google.maps.Marker( properties );
    

    
    google.maps.event.addListener( marker, 'click', function(e){
        toggleimages.call(this,e);  // modify any other markers that have the large icon before
        clickhandler.call(this,e);  // invoke clickhandler and set new large icon
    }.bind( marker ));
    
    markers.push( marker );
}
```